# Как в Django сделать анимацию загрузки если код во views долго обрабатывается?

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Есть страница на которой пользователь вводит 150 строк и отправляет их на сервер, сайту на обработку данных строк надо ~4-5 мин и по истечению этого времени сайт автоматически загрузит файл на ПК пользователя. Как мне сделать хоть какую-то анимацию чтобы пользователь понимал, что сайт работает, а не сдох?)

Comment: Создайте страницу с анимацией и переведите пользователя на неё, пока обрабатываете данные. А почему вы не отправляете данные построчно, по мере ввода пользователем, чтоб ускорить обработку?

Comment: @СергейКох Спасибо, в скором времени попробую. На счет построчного ввода это не возможно, так как от следуйщей строки зависит то что получится при обработке предыдущей